# setBackgroundColor(). (Android Studio) Can't understand how to use it to change the color of the background

Tags: android, kotlin, setbackground

I need the background to turn green when the button is clicked, many tutorials say to use:
**backgroundView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)** but it doesn't work.
[image: The code:]

It shows an error: **Type mismatch: inferred type is Color but Int was expected**
Can't understand what to do and why doesn't it work in my case.
Thank you

[image: Activity_main.xml looks like this:]

Comment: Which `Color` class are you using? `Color.GREEN` [should be an `Int`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#GREEN) which should work.

Comment: You should use [`Color.GREEN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#GREEN) instead of [`Color.Green`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Color#Green()). It seems you accidentally have imported `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color` instead of `android.graphics.Color`.

Comment: Thanks! I really didn’t notice that I imported androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color. Now everything works well

Answer (score 0):

```
backgroundView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
```

Points to remember:

The `Color` class should `import android.graphics.Color` and color GREEN should be in caps or you can use custom color from your colors.xml file using `getColor()` method